# can't install mysql2 using gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to create a project with mysql as database using rails

I use the following command :

```
 gem install mysql2
```

I get the following result in commandline :

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/sample/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170316-5426-f6rn3k.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for rb_big_cmp()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
-----
mysql client is missing. You may need to 'apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev' or 'yum install mysql-devel', and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/sample/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/sample/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/sample/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.4.5/gem_make.out
```

also as it mentions mysql client missing i tries to install the mentioned module but it did not work out.
can anyone provide a solution for this ?

Comment: Please install `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` then after try to install `mysql` gem

Comment: yeah i have done that i get the following error :
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: Try that command with `sudo`
`sudo` means `super user do`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

then

```
gem install mysql2
```